# Do companions benefit from wearing +Presence gear?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So, **Presence** as a stat, is defined as raising your companions health and damage/healing output. Awesome! A stat just for soloing, that's pretty handy.

And, using a +Presence stim, I see that, yes, my companion has just gained a bunch of health. Nifty. But +Presence can also be found on/added to gear with augments. And what I'm curious about is if companions will derive the same benefit if *the companion is wearing* gear with +Presence. And if so, does it do so by an amount greater than, or less than equipping them with a comparable amount of their preferred stats.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No.

Companions do not gain any benefit from wearing gear with +Presence.

To test this, I used two earpieces, both with 28 endurance, and one of which had +6 Presence as well.

When I equipped the +Presence earpiece onto my character, my companion gained +30 to max health. When I switched between the two earpieces on my companion, her health remained constant.

#### UPDATE: Still no, but for different reasons.

As of recent updates, companion gear is now entirely cosmetic in nature. The only two things affecting their stats are your influence rating with that companion and your Presence stat.